# average patient level variables on blocks defined by record_id

Tags: r, multi-level

I have a multilevel dataset of records with repeated measurements (example below).
I know in MLwiN it is possible to average these patient level variables (age, date_admission, date_discharge) on blocks defined by record_id, is it possible to do the same in R?
At the moment if I try and find the duration of stay (date_discharge - date_admission) it comes up as NA, presumably because they are in different rows. And if I try any multilevel modelling it restricts the dataset to obs_id "1" and "8" where age is present.
Many thanks, Annemarie

```
obs_id  record_id   day age tn  date_admission  date_discharge
1           1       0   40  122 12/02/2015 00:00        
2           1       1       90          
3           1       2       71          
4           1       3       71          
5           1       4       75          
6           1       5       73                  
7           1       182                         17/02/2015 00:00    
8           2       0   58  139 14/02/2015 00:00        
9           2       1       130         
10          2       2       119         
11          2       3       106         
12          2       4       102         
13          2       5       111                 
14          2       182                         19/02/2015 00:00
```

Comment: Your data does not correspond to a suitable format for analyses, cf for instance your date_admission/date_discharge stuff.

Comment: I agree. Why would you want the "average" date_admission? A better measure would be the average `date_discharge-date_admission`.

Comment: OK, I think I've expressed it poorly then. What I would like to do is format this dataset into some form that I can extract date_discharge-date_admission. And so that age applies to the whole of the record_id "1" rather than just obs_id "1". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you main question is how to get your data into a format so that is can be used by most R routines (such as lme4).

To get you example into R, I added some comma's. Next I converted the dates to the internal date format used by R (one of them actually, POSIXct):

```
lines <- "obs_id,  record_id,   day, age, tn,  date_admission,  date_discharge
1           ,1       ,0   ,40  ,122 ,12/02/2015 00:00,       
2           ,1       ,1   ,    ,90  ,        ,
3           ,1       ,2   ,    ,71  ,        ,
4           ,1       ,3   ,    ,71  ,        ,
5           ,1       ,4   ,    ,75  ,        ,
6           ,1       ,5   ,    ,73  ,                ,
7           ,1       ,182 ,   ,     ,                ,17/02/2015 00:00
8           ,2       ,0   ,58  ,139 ,14/02/2015 00:00,        
9           ,2       ,1   ,    ,130 ,        ,
10          ,2       ,2   ,    ,119 ,        ,
11          ,2       ,3   ,    ,106 ,        ,
12          ,2       ,4   ,    ,102 ,        ,
13          ,2       ,5   ,    ,111 ,                ,
14          ,2       ,182 ,   ,     ,                ,19/02/2015 00:00"

data <- read.csv(textConnection(lines))
data$date_admission <- as.POSIXct(data$date_admission, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
data$date_discharge <- as.POSIXct(data$date_discharge, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

You then need to have a date of admission and discharge for each of th records for a patient. There are dozens of ways to do this, but one of them is to use the `dplyr` package. We first group the data by `record_id` after which we can do computations per patient. Below I take the first and last values of the `date_admission`, `date_discharge` and `age` columns, but you could also calculate average values (although that wouldn't make much sense in this case):

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data %>% group_by(record_id) %>% mutate(
    date_admission = first(date_admission), 
    date_discharge = last(date_discharge), 
    age = first(age),
    duration = difftime(date_discharge, date_admission, "days"))
```

A quick google on `dplyr` will give you plenty of introductions to the package for more information. Especially the [data wrangling cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying so unsuccessfully to do!